# Installing and using pandas library in django application

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am trying to build the front-end structure of the energy usage user interface for my university. This requires retrieving data about each building's energy usage that is stored in excel sheets. Unfortunately, when I try to load the excel sheets, I get the following error even though I have already installed pandas:

```
import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

When I tried to reinstall it in the same folder as my project, I even got:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Please advise on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you try `pip install --user pandas`?

Comment: Install pandas via pip

Comment: yes I tried both

Comment: I did pip install --user pandas it showed me that it was successful but then when I run the program I got the same error for import pandas as pd

Comment: Sounds like there is a disconnect between the environment that you are running the django app in and the environment you are installing the pandas library into. Are you using a virtualenv by any chance?

Comment: No I am not using a virtualenv but I am using the IDE PyCharm

Comment: do you have more that 1 version of python installed ?

Comment: can you show the logs of `pip install pandas` command?

Comment: try install python via brew or just use conda https://conda.io/docs/index.html